# event dragmove and targetNode returns undefined

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I'm doing my first project in kineticJS; I have to drag some shapes on the canvas and in the meanwhile, I have to write somewhere on the page the coordinates of the shape in real time. In order to do this I use the event "dragmove" on the layer like this:

```
layer.on("dragmove",function(evt) {//detect shape and write stuff});
```

I used "targetNode" for catching the clicked shape.
The problem is this: if I use targetNode on a shape that is not part of any group, everything works, but if the node that has to be moved is part of a group, targetNode only works the first time and then return an undefined value for all times following (dragmove usually takes some time, not like dragstart or click).

I made a fiddle so you can see what I'm talking about:

http://jsfiddle.net/UScmU/

The 2 rects are in a group. if you click on a shape, an alert return its name, if you drag the circle or the rects, on the console will be written the shape's name.

I would appreciate some help. sorry for my english, I also hope the text is understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason `evt.targetNode` is only defined the first call on `dragmove` then it turns undefined, you can see this by doing this:

```
layer.on("dragmove",function(evt) {
  console.log(evt.targetNode);
  console.log(evt.targetNode.getName()+"");
});
```

Instead, try using defining `var nodo` outside of the event functions, and then set `nodo = evt.targetNode` on `mousedown`.

```
var nodo;
layer.on('mousedown', function(evt) {
    nodo = evt.targetNode;
});
layer.on("click", function (evt) {
    console.log(nodo.getName() + "");
});
layer.on("dragmove", function (evt) {
    console.log(nodo.getName() + "");
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/5q5KK/)

Comment: oh, it works! although I still don't know why.

thank you for your answer! you gave me a great help!